# Google search with discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am working on a bot who searches to google with given arguments.

So i just want it to send the link of the top result found on google kinda like this
[image: Example bot image]

so here is the code till now

```js
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./botconfig.json');
const prefix = '!g'

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Google-Bot is ready!');
})

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    
    const searchTopic = args.join(' ')
    
    //here it searches on google and provides the link
   
   message.channel.send(`Here is the result! \n ${result}`)

})

bot.login(config.token)
```

thank you for reading!

Comment: Is there some more code that we're missing? `result` is not defined.

Comment: no i meant store the link in a result variable, and then send it through message.channel.send

Comment: Have you tried [google-search-results](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-search-results)?

Comment: i get an error while installing that package

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a link to the requested argument by using `https://google.com/search?q=${args.join('+')}`, then send it.

---

Example:

```
message.channel.send(`https://google.com/search?q=${args.join('+')}`)
```

You also need to join with a `+` because google encodes any spaces with a plus symbol.

I also have a suggestion that could lead to a potential problem.
First, make sure you're using the `slice` attribute after your args.join('+') to exclude the prefix from the argument. So you could use `args.join('+').slice(1)`.

Here is your improved code:

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./botconfig.json');
const prefix = '!g'

bot.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Google-Bot is ready!');
})

bot.on('message', message => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);

const searchTopic = args.join('+').slice(1)
let googleResult = `https://google.com/search?q=${searchTopic}`

let searchEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor("#00ff00")
.setDescription(`Here's what Google came up with for ${searchTopic}!\n${googleResult}`)
message.channel.send(searchEmbed)

})

bot.login(config.token)
```